# How do I set up Outlook to send a auto reply during a certain hour of the day every day?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, auto-reply

I would like to protect myself from unreasonable demands during my work day.  One of those is telling people that I will not respond to any emails before 3pm.

I'd like to set up a rule in outlook that replies to all emails before 3pm with a specific message. I'd like this to be done every day, no matter the date.

How do I set this up?

I've scoured Google best I can so far, and I think, based on a Exchange forum, that a script might be needed for this.  But what I found so far was only server side scripts. I need something on my own machine.

references:
http://www.telnetport25.com/2012/01/exchange-2010-out-of-office-fun-with-set-mailboxautoreplyconfiguration/

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrclientslegacy/thread/08a033ce-ea79-4dec-bd7c-4d617cc52e02/

Comment: Which version of MS office do you have?

Comment: the latest, 2010

Comment: Check out this article http://www.it.cornell.edu/services/outlook/howto/email/out-of-office.cfm

Comment: @avirk "time range" in that article is referring to a date and time, not a time per for every day.  I've scoured google best I can so far, I think a script might be needed for this.

Comment: Just got the "popular question badge" But not a single upvote :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where your name is in the To box.

```vba
Public Sub Check_ReceivedTime(newMail As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim obj As Object
Dim ReceivedHour As Integer
Dim newReply As MailItem
Dim msg As String

ReceivedHour = Hour(newMail.ReceivedTime)

If ReceivedHour < 15 Then

    Set newReply = newMail.reply
    msg = "I will respond some time after 3 pm."

    CreateMail newReply.To, msg

Else

    Debug.Print "After 3. Do not sent the automated reply."

End If

Set newReply = Nothing

End Sub


Private Sub CreateMail(ReplyAddress As String, msg As String)

Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set objMail = CreateItem(olMailItem)

With objMail
    .To = ReplyAddress
    .Body = msg

    .Display
    ' or
    ' .Send

End With

End Sub
```

Edit: Paste the code into the VBA editor.  The code will be availabel in "run a script".

See also http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/

Comment: Can you explain little bit how will it get work?

Comment: Thank you, I'll mark the answer correct when I confirm it works :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not the intention to shamelessly advertise my application, but I have developed an online application where I try to solve this exact problem.

The tool can help you with the following situations:

- recurring out of office's for specific days / hours
- plan upfront on or more one-off out of office's
- manage multiple out of office messages

More info, [https://www.notin.today](https://www.notin.today/?utm_source=superuser.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=early_access)

bob

note: I am always looking for people who want to use this tool and give feedback. Hands-on feedback so that I can further improve the tool. Thanks!